# Android Studio won't start new project, help! (gets transparent)

Tags: java, android, sdk

when i install it and try open for the first time, it works perfectly, but when i tried after, and click in "Start a new Android Studio project", the window opens, but gets transparent for ever(see in the image). it gives no error alerts, files missing, nothing.
[image]

after that, i tried to:

update all tools and SDKs, not works.

run it as ADM, not works.

run this with nothing more running to have more power of the pc, not works.

add the "JAVA_HOME" system variable with the JDKs and JREs locations, not works.

install individual SDK tools, not works.

uninstall and reinstall all JREs, JDKs and Android Studio, not works.

Change JREs and JDKs versions to older ones, not works.

search for the Minimal System Requirements to run it (that you can see here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

and my pc supports i guess (that have 4gb RAM, 150gb of free space on the install location, AMD Sempron 145 2.8ghz processor, Win 7 32-bit, 1280x1024px screen resolution and all JREs, JDKs and SDKs needed).

yesterday i tried to change the installation location to another HD, not works too

and in my last try, i undo my pc with a System Restore to 4 days before the first installation, nothing of this works

anyone knows what i can do to solve this? if not, exist another program that i can use instead of the Android Studio? i'm a newbie in android development, i relly relly need some help pls :(

sorry my bad english and the big post, i'm just trying to be more specific as possible.

Thanks in advance, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

go to your user directory.
Example : C:\Users\yourName.
delete the directory..
`.AndroidStudioX.X`
if you have few of them delete all of them.
this should reset Android Studio as a fresh install
helped me a lot of times.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it don't works :( still doing the same think, i first tried to delete the directorys and run the AS and it gets the same problem, so i uninstall and install it again, but the transparent window persists